# Arreglar fondo en Alert Personalizado

Tags: java, android, xml

Estoy creando un `Alert` personalizado con un `CardView` para tener bordes redondeados, el problema es que me muestra un borde blanco al final:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría saber cómo quitar esos bordes blancos en las esquinas. Este es el diseño de mi `CardView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:cardCornerRadius="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llTODO"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <EditText
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/nombre_bd"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/guardar_cerrar"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Así lo creo y ejecuto en mi actividad:

```
private void control_dark_mode(){
    switch (getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            alerta_Nombre_Tabla();
            break;
    }
}

private void alerta_Nombre_Tabla(){
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    AlertDialog anuncio = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    final View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_nombre_base_de_datos, null);
    final LinearLayout ll = view.findViewById(R.id.llTODO);
    
    ll.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gris));
    final EditText nombre_bd = view.findViewById(R.id.nombre_bd);
    nombre_bd.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.negro));
    nombre_bd.setHint("Ingrese el nombre de su taller");
    nombre_bd.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
    nombre_bd.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
    final Button guardar_cerrar = view.findViewById(R.id.guardar_cerrar);
    guardar_cerrar.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blanco));
    try {
        guardar_cerrar.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(nombre_bd.getText().toString() == ""
                    || nombre_bd.equals("")
                    || nombre_bd.getText().toString() == null
                    || TextUtils.isEmpty(nombre_bd.getText())){
                nombre_bd.setError("Debe ingresar un nombre válido.");
                nombre_bd.requestFocus();
            }else{
                nombreTallerPreferencia.guardarValor(nombre_bd.getText().toString());
                anuncio.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception exception){
        Log.d("NOMBREBD", "alerta_Nombre_Tabla: " + exception.getMessage());
    }
    anuncio.setView(view);
    anuncio.show();
}

onCreate: 

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    control_dark_mode();
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:**

Al modificar la siguiente línea:

```
AlertDialog anuncio = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
```

Por esta:

```
AlertDialog anuncio = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.FondoDialog).create();
```

Se afecta el ancho quedando así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso el AlertDialog tiene un fondo blanco, debes cambiarlo a transparente para que no se vean los espacios en blanco, agrega en tu archivo `styles.xml`

```
<style name="FondoDialog" parent="android:Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

y cuando crees el `AlertDialog` define el estilo:

```
//AlertDialog anuncio = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
AlertDialog anuncio = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.FondoDialog).create();
```

Comment: Eso, de alguna manera afectó el diseño del mismo en relación a su ancho establecido. Dejo captura editando la pregunta